# how to get the scripts format

Tags: internationalization, icu

I am seeing this in my browse:

```
\xe18\xe23\xe23\xe21\xe0a\xe32\xe15
```

I believe it's some valid Thai scripts? But how do I know the format of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know if this is the correct answer without more details but the sample you provided looks like a [hexadecimal escape sequence](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#hexadecimal).

```
\x followed by two hexadecimal characters represent a character by its ASCII code
```

You can check directly wha the value is in your browser console:

```js
console.log("\xe18\xe23\xe23\xe21\xe0a\xe32\xe15");
```

Output is:

```
á8â3â3â1àaã2á5
```